# Nested form field with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I'm loading nested fields. It works fine if I only have one div `fields` but if I have 2 of them for different form field types it doubles the request and it adds 2 field instead of 1. I tried to use the function `.closest` but it's not working at all

here is what I have

```js
  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
    $(event.target).closest('.nested-form'), function(e) { 
      var regexp, time;
      time = new Date().getTime();
      regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
      $('.fields').append($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
      return e.preventDefault();
    };
  });
```

then inside my form I have

```html
<div class="nested-form">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="user[talent_genres_attributes][0][genre]" id="user_talent_genres_attributes_0_genre">
        <option value="Musicians">Musicians</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Acting">Acting</option>
        <option value="Modeling">Modeling</option>
        <option value="DJs">DJs</option></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="add_fields btn btn-secondary" data-id="70350559861960" data-fields="<fieldset><div class='form-group'><select name=&quot;user[talent_genres_attributes][70350559861960][genre]&quot; id=&quot;user_talent_genres_attributes_70350559861960_genre&quot;><option value=&quot;Musicians&quot;>Musicians</option><option value=&quot;Acting&quot;>Acting</option><option value=&quot;Modeling&quot;>Modeling</option><option value=&quot;DJs&quot;>DJs</option></select><input as=&quot;hidden&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; name=&quot;user[talent_genres_attributes][70350559861960][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;user_talent_genres_attributes_70350559861960__destroy&quot; /><a class=&quot;remove_record btn btn-danger&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;>Delete</a></div></fieldset>" href="#">Add Genres</a>

<div class="nested-form">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select name="user[talent_genres_attributes][1][genre]" id="user_talent_genres_attributes_1_genre">
       <option selected="selected" value="Musicians">Musicians</option>
       <option value="Acting">Acting</option>
       <option value="Modeling">Modeling</option>
       <option value="DJs">DJs</option></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="add_fields btn btn-secondary" data-id="70350580425060" data-fields="<fieldset><div class='form-group'><select name=&quot;user[talent_locations_attributes][70350580425060][location]&quot; id=&quot;user_talent_locations_attributes_70350580425060_location&quot;><option value=&quot;Los Angeles&quot;>Los Angeles</option><option value=&quot;Chicago&quot;>Chicago</option><option value=&quot;Detroit&quot;>Detroit</option><option value=&quot;Miami&quot;>Miami</option><option value=&quot;New York&quot;>New York</option><option value=&quot;San Francisco&quot;>San Francisco</option></select><input as=&quot;hidden&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; name=&quot;user[talent_locations_attributes][70350580425060][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;user_talent_locations_attributes_70350580425060__destroy&quot; /><a class=&quot;remove_record btn btn-danger&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;>Delete</a></div></fieldset>" href="#">Add Locations</a>
```

BTW this is the version I had before that added fields in both `.fields` div container

```js
  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
      var regexp, time;
      time = new Date().getTime();
      regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
      $('.fields').append($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
      return eevent.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: are the `nested-form` and th `a` tags all siblings? if so, use `prev()` instead of `closest()`

Comment: also `$('.fields')` returns both `.fields` divs, use something like `$(this).find('.fields')` to grab only the one inside that `.nested-form` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically do something along the lines of:

`<div id='fields_area'></div>`

Then use `$('#fields_area').append('.fields_container');` to add fields

and `$(this).closest('.fields_container').remove();` (triggered by a button in .fields_container) to remove fields.

Wrap your data-* in a `<div class="fields_container"></div>` and this should do it.

Edit: Checkout `cocoon` : https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: I ended up using cocoon and looking into the source code to see how it was compared to wha I had done.